# Is asking about a processor's specification on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

Not the specification from the design point of view but a specification like

```
3rd Generation Intel core(3M Cache, 1.9GHz with 2GB Discrete Base)
```

which I came across when I was looking for laptops. Instead of 2GB Discrete Base I have read `with UMA`. I wanted to know what the `2GB Discrete Base` means and how does it effect the performance. Is this on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say this question is too consumer-oriented, and can be labeled as "not related to electronic design". But in case you want to go deeper in the technology, you may look more specifically for "discrete base", if it even means anything but marketing :)

Comment: seems like [su] to me.